# not able to install Android studio showing error:- could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main

Tags: android-studio

Android studio is not starting, showing the following error:

```
could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main
```

I don't understand what to do.

Please help me.

Comment: have you set `JAVA_HOME` to latest JDK version in system enviourment variable. In my case i did this then its start working!

Comment: i set JAVA_HOME with JDK 1.7.0.79. Is that ok or i should change it to jdk 1.8 –